# Apache Camel - NTLM Configuration

Tags: apache, apache-camel, ntlm

I want to call NTLM authenticated service through apache camel. It fails with 401 status if I call direct  without any Java DSL configuration as below, IS there a way to add NTLM authentication mode , user name and password when call the service?

```
from("direct:link.XXX.soap.out")                    
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/soap+xml"))
.log(LoggingLevel.WARN,"routes","SOAP message:\n${body}")
.to("http://projectname.csq.YYY.net/api/service")
.to("file:logs/XXX.out.soapreply");
```

Answer (score 1):

Camel uses Apache HTTP client for the HTTP producer. NTLM should be [supported](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga//ntlm.html) out of the box by default.

However, this applies to version 4 of HTTP client. Version 3 has only limited NTLM support (reverse engineered). To use version 4 in Camel, do `.to("http4://projectname.csq.YY.net/api/service")` instead.

Comment: Yes, my camel is running on linux server where NT authentication was't defaulted. So I need to explicitly specify the NT user id and password while posting request. any thoughts?

Comment: But do you really use the http4 component and not the http3 which it seems like you are in the sample code?